# MSAL, Azure MobileService and Auto REST calls get 401 Unauthorized

Tags: rest, azure, authentication, azure-ad-msal, autorest

I have an app (currently in UWP) that makes use of MobileServiceClient and AutoRest to an Azure App Service API App. I successfully used the winfbsdk and can authenticate thru that and then get it to login to MobileService.LoginAsync with the FB access token as a JObject. I also take that JObject and send it in the x-zumo-auth header when making calls to the API App via AutoRest within the app.
What I would like to do is be able to authenticate using MicrosoftAccount. If I use MobileService.LoginAsync, I cannot get the proper token and pass it along to AutoRest - it always comes back as 401 Unauthorized.
I tried to used MSAL, but it returns a Bearer token and passing that along also comes back as 401 Unauthorized.
Is there any good way to do this? I started on the route of MSAL since that would support Windows desktop, UWP and Xamarin Forms which will be ideal. I just need info on how to get the proper token from it to pass along to an AutoRest HttpClient that goes back to the Azure App Service API App.

*Update:*
If I use the following flow, it works with Facebook, but **not with MicrosoftAccount.**

-Azure AppService with WebAPI (and swagger for testing via a browser)
-Security setup through the Azure Dashboard on the service and configured to allow Facebook or MicrosoftAccount


1. On my UWP app, using winfbsdk, I login with Facebook, then grab the FBSession.AccessTokenData.AccessToken and insert that into a JObject:

```
  JObject token = JObject.FromObject
  (new{access_token = fbSession.AccessTokenData.AccessToken});
```

2. Login to MobileServiceClient

```
  user = await App.MobileService.LoginAsync
  (MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Facebook, token);
```

3. Login to API App with HttpClient and retrieve the token to use in X-ZUMO-AUTH

   ```
   using (var client = new HttpClient())
   {
       client.BaseAddress = App.MobileService.MobileAppUri; 
           var jsonToPost = token;

           var contentToPost = new StringContent(
            JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonToPost),
            Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
           var asyncResult = await client.PostAsync(
           "/.auth/login/" + provider.ToString(),
           contentToPost);

           if (asyncResult.Content == null)
           {
               throw new InvalidOperationException("Result from call was null.");
               return false;
           }
           else
           {
               if (asyncResult.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
               {
                   var resultContentAsString = asyncResult.Content.AsString();

                   var converter = new ExpandoObjectConverter();
                   dynamic responseContentAsObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(
                   resultContentAsString, converter);

                   var applicationToken = responseContentAsObject.authenticationToken;

                   ApiAppClient.UpdateXZUMOAUTHToken(applicationToken);
               }
           }
       }
   ```
4. ApiAppClient.UpdateXZUMOAUTH call just does the following:

   ```
       if (this.HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Contains("x-zumo-auth") == true)
       {
           this.HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("x-zumo-auth");
       }

       this.HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-zumo-auth", applicationToken);
   ```
5. Any subsequent calls using the ApiAppClient (created with AutoRest from the swagger json of my Azure AppService WebAPI) contain the x-zumo-auth header and are properly authenticated.

   **The problem occurs when trying to use MicrosoftAccount.** I cannot seem to obtain the proper token to use in x-zumo-auth from either MSAL or LoginWithMicrosoftAsync.
   For #1 above, when trying for MicrosoftAccount, I used MSAL as follows:

   ```
   AuthenticationResult result = await MSAuthentication_AcquireToken();  
   JObject token = JObject.FromObject(new{access_token = result.Token});
   ```

And MSAuthentication_AcquireToken is defined below, using interfaces and classes as suggested in the Azure samples: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-xamarin-native-v2

```
      private async Task<AuthenticationResult> MSAuthentication_AcquireToken()
       {
       IMSAcquireToken at = new MSAcquireToken();
        try
        {
            AuthenticationResult res;
            res = await at.AcquireTokenAsync(App.MsalPublicClient, App.Scopes);

            return res;
        }
      }
```

**Update - ok with MobileServiceClient, but still not working with MSAL**
I got it working with MobileServiceClient as follows:
1. Use MobileService.LoginAsync
2. Take the returned User.MobileServiceAuthenticationToken
3. Set the X-ZUMO-AUTH header to contain the User.MobileServiceAuthenticationToken

```
user = await App.MobileService.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.MicrosoftAccount);  
applicationToken = user.MobileServiceAuthenticationToken;  
ApiAppClient.UpdateAppAuthenticationToken(applicationToken);
```

**MSAL still not working!**
So the original question still remains, what part of the token returned from MSAL do we need to pass on to X-ZUMO-AUTH or some other header so that calls to the Azure AppService WebAPI app will authenticate?

Answer (score 0):

> I have an app (currently in UWP) that makes use of MobileServiceClient and AutoRest to an Azure App Service API App. I successfully used the winfbsdk and can authenticate thru that and then get it to login to MobileService.LoginAsync with the FB access token as a JObject. I also take that JObject and send it in the x-zumo-auth header when making calls to the API App via AutoRest within the app.

According to your description, I assumed that you are using [Client-managed authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library#clientflow). You directly contact the identity provider and then provide the token during the login with your mobile back-end, then you could leverage `MobileServiceClient.InvokeApiAsync` to call your API APP, which would add the `X-ZUMO-AUTH` header with the value `authenticationToken` after you invoke `MobileServiceClient.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Facebook, token);`

> What I would like to do is be able to authenticate using MicrosoftAccount. If I use MobileService.LoginAsync, I cannot get the proper token and pass it along to AutoRest - it always comes back as 401 Unauthorized. I tried to used MSAL, but it returns a Bearer token and passing that along also comes back as 401 Unauthorized. Is there any good way to do this?

AFAIK, **for the client-flow authentication patterns (AAD, Facebook, Google)**, the `token` parameter for `LoginAsync` would look like `{"access_token":"{the_access_token}"}`.

**For the client-flow authentication (Microsoft Account)**, you could leverage `MobileServiceClient.LoginWithMicrosoftAccountAsync("{Live-SDK-session-authentication-token}")`, also you could use `LoginAsync` with the `token` parameter of the value `{"access_token":"{the_access_token}"}` or `{"authenticationToken":"{Live-SDK-session-authentication-token}"}`. I have tested `LoginAsync` with the `access_token` from MSA and retrieve the logged info as follows:

[image]

In summary, when you retrieve the `authentionToken` after you have logged with your mobile back-end, you could add the `X-ZUMO-AUTH` header to each of your API APP requests with the `authentionToken`.

[image]

For more details, you could refer to this official document about [authentication works in App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-overview#how-authentication-works-in-app-service).

**UPDATE**

I have checked this https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-xamarin-native-v2 and used [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to capture the network packages when authenticating the user and get an access token. I found that MSAL is working against [Microsoft Graph and REST](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/get-started/rest) and when the user is logged, you could only retrieve the `access_token` and `id_token`, and both of them could not be used for single sign-on with your mobile back-end.

While the official code sample about Client-managed authentication for Azure Mobile Apps with MSA is using the [Live SDK](https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK). As the [Live SDK REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn659752.aspx) mentioned about [signing users](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn659750.aspx), you could get an **access token** and an **authentication token** which is used for single sign-on scenario. Also, I have checked the [Server-managed authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library#serverflow) and found that app service authentication / authorization for MSA also uses the Live SDK REST API.
In summary, you could not use MSAL for client-managed authentication with MSA, for client-managed authentication, you need to leverage Live SDK to retrieve the `authentication_token` then invoke `MobileServiceClient.LoginWithMicrosoftAccountAsync("{Live-SDK-session-authentication-token}")` to retrieve the `authenticationToken` from your mobile backend. Or you could just leverage server-managed authentication for MSA. For more details about Live SDK, you could refer to [LiveSDK](https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK).

Comment: All this works fine as in my original post when I use Facebook as the authentication provider. However, it does not work when taking the "Bearer" token (AuthenticationResult.Token) that comes back from MSAL and insert that into X-ZUMO-AUTH for the API APP calls. It still gets Unauthorized.

Comment: Also, if I use MobileServiceClient.LoginAsync or LoginWithMicrosoftAccountAsync and take the MobileServiceUser.MobileServiceAuthenticationToken and use that in X-ZUMO-AUTH it gets Unauthorized.

Comment: And if I take the valid MobileServiceClient.Login and then use InvokeApiAsync and hit the /.auth/me end point, I get a response that includes "access_token" in the content response. But if I use that access_token in X-ZUMO-AUTH, it still comes back Unauthorized

Comment: Thanks for the update - this explains what I found also, that if I used Server-managed authentication (MobileServiceClient.LoginAsync), I could then use the returned token with my AutoRest calls. I will look into the LiveSDK. Is there any plans to make MSAL work for single sign-on?

Comment: So the LiveSDK is being deprecated and would not be a good idea to use going forward for new apps. I also found in [active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native) that this MSAL sample is designed to login and then use it to hit a WebAPI - maybe that only works with AAD B2C and not MSA yet?

Comment: AFAIK, since the app service authentication for MSA is using Live SDK and receive the `authentication_token` from client-authentication to exchange the app auth token, per my understanding, MSAL with MSA could not meet your requirement. For SSO wth MSA via MSAL, I assumed that azure app service authentication need to provide the feature to accept the token(e.g. `id_token`) and handle the SSO logic. You could add  your [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps).

Comment: I'm having this same problem. App Services backend, Microsoft Accounts. Trying to get the user to authorize once, and be able to authenticate against both. I've tried every possible scenario, client-flow, server-flow, etc. Except for the Live SDK, which is being deprecated. No idea where to go from here, did you ever resolve this?

Comment: @MattF - I found that if I setup AAD B2C and attached that to Easy Auth for the app as the AAD setup, then I could use MSAL and take the returned tokens (result.AccessToken) and authenticate to my web api with it. Looks like the way to do this going forward would be to add MSA and FB, etc (now up to 20 providers) into Azure AD B2C and then have it all flow through the Easy Auth AAD setup. See the example from CGillum dev blog, [link](https://cgillum.tech/2016/05/27/app-service-auth-and-azure-ad-b2c/)

Comment: @MattF - After getting the AccessToken from MSAL, you have to set it as the Bearer header and make sure that you remove any reference to x-zumo-auth. Otherwise, I still got unauthorized when trying to hit my API. While this will work, I have still found no way to get Live SDK working or any other library that would then give access to MSA info if the user allows it (like friends, profile pic, etc).

Comment: This is all great to know. But what if you want to make use of Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Service (because it offers an easy way of working with your Azure App Service hosted API and Tables)? Because MSAL returns a bearer token that is added to the HttpClient Authorization Header, it seems to be not possible to use MSAL for authenticating against AADB2C and then pass whatever token you get to MobileServiceClient. Because the latter only accepts X-ZUMO-AUTH with an AuthenticationToken. Maybe I don't get something here, but there must be a solution for this Scenario to get it working.